# Place a fixed height button at the bottom of the screen always

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I wish to keep a button at the bottom of my Activity screen. It has to be fixed irrespective of the size of scrollview above it. The problem is that once the textviews of the scrollview take up some place, the height of my button keeps decreasing and it eventually gets pushed out of the activity screen. This is the layout I am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvBanner" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Practice Exam" />


    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/Scroll" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvDesc" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center" android:paddingTop="40dp" android:text="@string/welcom"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvURL" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="hello" android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:typeface="sans" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="bottom">

        <Button android:id="@+id/btBottom" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Enter" />

    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

I have also tried using android:weight=1 and android:layout_height=0dp in the Scrollview. But this removes the entire Scrollview portion from my activity and I can't see anything.

I do know that there are many similar questions asked about this and believe me, I have tried many of these. However, none of the tricks have worked for me. I have spent almost half a day fixing this. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a case like this always use RelativeLayouts. A LinearLayout is not intended for such a usage.

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <Button android:id="@+id/btBottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Enter" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

   <ScrollView
      ...
      android:layout_above="@id/btnGetMoreResults"/>
</RelativeLayour>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try using RealativeLayout instead of Linear, and then you could use

```
android:layout_above="@+id/btBottom"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need 'alignParentBottom' in your button like this

```
    <Button android:id="@+id/btBottom" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:text="Enter" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not wrap `Button` to `RelativeLayout`
2. Set layout_height of `ScrollView` to 0dp
3. Add layout_weight of `ScrollView` to 1

Answer (score 0):

For this it would probably be a good idea if you used RelativeLayout for the outer wrapper layout. Then you could just set the layout with the button inside to LinearLayout and set `layout_alignParentButtom="true"` while you set your `@+id/Scroll` to `layout_alignParentTop="true"`

Also, you should probably set the layout with the button inside´s height to `wrap_content` instead of `fill_parent`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a `LinearLayout` at top level at all ?
Choose a `RelativeLayout` with fill/fill and the following three childern (no further nesting !):

1) TextView with `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

2) Button with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

3) ScrollView with `android:layout_below=@id/textview_id` and `android:layout_above="@id/button_id"`

I didn't test it though, but give it a try.